# Django FormSet show two formset

Tags: django, django-models

I try to do a table, and when I click in a Store show me the data, and let me edit. But when I try to do this show me two form sets, one with the corect data and other empty.

I have try to follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/ tutorial but I dont understand very well.
[Here is the image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcTG9.png)

**HTML:**

```
{% extends 'layout.html'%}
    {# Load the tag library #}
    {% load bootstrap4 %}

    {# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}

    {# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
    {% bootstrap_messages %}

    {% block content%}
    <form action="/favorita/store/0/" method="POST" class="form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% bootstrap_formset formset %}
      {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </button>
      {% endbuttons %}
    </form>
    {%endblock%}
```

**View:**

```
def store(request, id):
StoreFormSet = modelformset_factory(Store, exclude=())
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = StoreFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        return render(request, 'stores/index.html', {'title': 'Favorita Stores'})
else:
    if id == 0:
        formset = formset_factory(StoreForm)
    else:
        stores_search = Store.objects.filter(id = id)
        formset = StoreFormSet(queryset=stores_search)
    return render(request, 'store/details.html', {'formset': formset})
```

**Model:**

```
class Store(models.Model):
city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
store_type = models.ForeignKey(StoreType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
cluster = models.IntegerField(default=0)
location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**ModelForm:**

```
class StoreForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Store
    fields = ['city', 'store_type', 'cluster', 'location']
```

I only need the one with the data.

Comment: just edited my answer with a more readable code for your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set extra to 0, by default django set it to 1.

Look at the modelformset_factory definition:

```
modelformset_factory(model, form=ModelForm, formfield_callback=None, formset=BaseModelFormSet, extra=1, can_delete=False, can_order=False, max_num=None, fields=None, exclude=None, widgets=None, validate_max=False, localized_fields=None, labels=None, help_texts=None, error_messages=None, min_num=None, validate_min=False, field_classes=None)
```

So for your case :

```
StoreFormSet = modelformset_factory(Store, exclude=(),extra=0)
```

More info about extra form doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#limiting-the-number-of-editable-objects

> Limiting the number of editable objects
>
> As with regular formsets, you can use the max_num and extra parameters
>   to modelformset_factory() to limit the number of extra forms
>   displayed.
>
> max_num does not prevent existing objects from being displayed.
>
> Also, extra=0 doesn’t prevent creation of new model instances as you
>   can add additional forms with JavaScript or just send additional POST
>   data. Formsets don’t yet provide functionality for an “edit only” view
>   that prevents creation of new instances.
>
> If the value of max_num is greater than the number of existing related
>   objects, up to extra additional blank forms will be added to the
>   formset, so long as the total number of forms does not exceed max_num:

For you code a little bit of rewritting to make it simplier:

```
def store(request, id):
    #define the modleformset
    StoreFormSet = modelformset_factory(Store, form= StoreForm, extra=0)

    #get the queryset
    stores_search = Store.objects.filter(id = id)

    #Simplify the form logic

    #create the formset
    formset = StoreFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, queryset=stores_search)

    #validate the form
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        return render(request, 'stores/index.html', {'title': 'Favorita Stores'})

    #if the form is not valid it will simply render the page with your formset again (and errors if the formset contains errors)
    return render(request, 'store/details.html', {'formset': formset})
```